# Pandas could not filter a dataframe "not in" list

Tags: python, pandas

Working with a large Chinese DataFrame with near 2 million records.
Plotted out the Gender distribution, but got two unexpected bars with corrupted characters.
Assumed that the data is corrupted, so I wanted to filter out the records with those two unexpected values.
So I wrote,

```
db['Gender'] = db['Gender'].astype("category")
expected_list = ["Male","Female"]
unexpected = ~(db["Gender"].isin(expected_list))
exception = db[unexpected]
print(exception)
```

However, the new dataframe "exception" is completely unfiltered and contains all records from the original. Don't know what went wrong.

Comment: For me working well, what is your pandas version?

Comment: also show the first 5 rows of your df if u can

Comment: This is not a reproducible example (MCVE). Please post a reproducible example. Cut it down to the absolute minimum rows needed to reproduce. Based on what you said, I'd look at the corrupted text, Unicode encoding etc.

Answer (score 0):

Self-solved:
Hidden space character appended during the encoding translation between Chinese and English. Will always try to strip() first from now on. Thanks for the hints.